# validate fields generically in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where i need to validate all the fields on onChange event. I have handled onChange event generically but how can i validate those fields generically? Here is what i have done

```
class Service extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    APIKey: '',
    APISecret: '',
    errors: {}
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    let nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    this.setState(this.validateField(nextState));
  };

  validateField(state) {
    console.log('state', state);
    // let errors = {};
    // if (state.cloudName.length === 0) {
    //   errors.cloudName = 'Cloud Name cannot be empty';
    // }
    // return Object.assign({}, state, errors);
  }


  render() {
    const { APIKey, APISecret, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        <TextFieldGroup
          id="formControlsText"
          name="APIKey"
          type="text"
          value={APIKey}
          label="API Key"
          placeholder="Enter API Key"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
        <TextFieldGroup
          id="formControlsText"
          name="APISecret"
          type="text"
          value={APISecret}
          label="API Secret"
          placeholder="Enter API Secret"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          required
        />
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Service;
```

Can anyone please guide me the way to handle validation generically in the way i am trying to?

**UPDATE**

```
handleChange = event => {
  let nextState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
  this.setState(this.validateField(nextState));
};

validateField(state) {
  console.log('state', state);
  const validate = ['APIKey', 'APISecret'];
  let validation = validate.forEach(field => {
    if (state[field].length === 0) {
      state.errors[field] = 'This field cannot be empty';
    }
  });
  console.log(validation);
  return Object.assign({}, state);
}
```

With the above code, if i touch on any field and write some text, the error will be shown on other fields. If i write some text, the error does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

> please guide me the way to handle validation generically in the way i am trying to

Have a structure like :

```
{
  'fieldName': [validator1, validation2, ...]
}
```

And then you can run these validators in sequence. Each validator can be `value => Error | null`

## More

- [Formstate](https://formstate.github.io/#/) comes with type definitions and handles validations like this (i.e. using simple `value => Promise<string | null>` functions)

Comment: where should i use that structure? Sorry i did not understand you.

Comment: I have updated my question with code. Can you please look at this, if you are free?

Answer (score 0):

I could do this the following way

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }, () => {
      this.validateField([fieldName]);
    });
  };

  handleBlur = event => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    this.validateField([fieldName]);
  };


  validateField = validate => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    console.log(errors, validate);
    let hasError = false;
    validate.forEach(field => {
      if (this.state[field].length === 0) {
        hasError = true;
        errors[field] = `${field} cannot be empty`;
      } else {
        errors[field] = '';
      }
    });
    this.setState({ errors });
    return !hasError;
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.validateField(['APIKey', 'APISecret'])) {
      console.log('you can now submit the data');
    }
  };
```

I think it will be better when putting validateField as validate.js and call that function. But i have no clear idea on how can i use the state that is used in validateField function if i keep this separately so i can call this function wherever it is needed. Please feel free to share your thoughts.